# Swift 4 trying to use Realm Database Object as an instance variable

Tags: swift, set, realm

I come from a java programming background. I am trying to set my instance variables of classA from classB like so in order to do calculations with other variables that go into a Realm and are used to communicate with bluetooth using RXSwift so I am trying to convert from object type Measurement to TestRes.

```
public class classA {

    var mTestResult:TestRes?

    func setTestResult(measurement:Measurement){
        self.mTestResult?.id = measurement.measurementId
        print("Test Id:     \(self.mTestResult?.id)")
        print("Measured Id: \(measurement.measurementId)")

        self.mTestResult?.oilType = measurement.oilType
        print("Test Oil Type:     \(self.mTestResult?.oilType)")
        print("Measured Oil Type: \(measurement.oilType)")
    }

}
```

ClassB's function is right below:

```
public class ClassB{

    private func send304and306(measurement: Measurement, connectedPeripheral: Peripheral) -> Observable<Measurement> {

        let response2 = MeasurementData(response: response)     
        //added            
        dump(measurement)
        let results = HW2_1_Calculate()
        results.setTestResult(measurement: measurement)

        results.run()//CRASH HERE because my measurements are not being set

        realm.add(results.mTestResult, update: true)
        print("about to dump results")
        dump(results)
        try realm.commitWrite()
    }
}
```

The output I get in the debugger from this is

Test Id: nil 
Measured Id: 13fvasl-f4vr-4fsb-4kgv-4kvlvnfsv 
Test Oil Type: nil 
Measured Oil Type:

My instance variable of type TestRes goes into a realm data base and looks like so.

```
class TestRes: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var oilType:String = ""
}

class Measurement: Object {
    @objc dynamic var measurementId = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var oilType: String = ""    
}
```

In reality TestRes has more complexity to it than Measurement. Anyways why is ClassA instance var not being set to the value I am telling it to be equal to?

Comment: I can't see where you're instantiating mTestResult. It's an optional value (i.e. initializes to nil).

Comment: Noted. I will change that as well. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix this of course right after I posted it..

anyways I was not using the init() to construct the object!
in order to fix my problem I put this in ClassA

```
init(measurement:Measurement){
    self.mTestResult = setTestResult(measurement: measurement)
    print("Test Id:     \(self.mTestResult?.id)")
}
```

and then in ClassB I created the object with that constructor like so below.

```
let results = HW2_1_Calculate(measurement:measurement)
```